# Connecting an image in firebase storage, to a data document in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am trying to access a single, specific image from firebase storage based on a data document. I currently have a data document with 3 fields: name, price, and imageLink. I want the image link to connect somehow to an image that I have saved in my storage so that I can display the price and name with the correct corresponding image. Not sure what I need to put in the imageLink and how to get a single image.

This is how I am uploading the image to firebase

```
`function uploadImage () {
if(imageUpload == null) return
const imageRef = ref(storage, `images/${imageUpload.name + v4()}`)
setImageUrl("image ref", imageRef._location.path_)
uploadBytes(imageRef, imageUpload).then(() => {
  alert("Image Uploaded")
})
```

}`

and this is what I am doing to try access the image

```
const createWatchListing = async () => {
// uploadImage()
await addDoc(watchCollectionRef, {name: watchName, price: watchPrice, watchImageUrl: imageUrl})
```

}

```
 <div>
          <h3>{watch.name}</h3>
          <h3>${watch.price}</h3>
          <img src={watch.watchImageUrl} /> <------
          <form onSubmit={() => {updateWatch(watch.id, updatedWatchName, updatedWatchPrice )}}>
            <input placeholder={watch.name} onChange={e => {setUpdatedWatchName(e.target.value)}}/>
            <input type="number" placeholder={watch.price} onChange={e => {setUpdatedWatchPrice(e.target.value)}}/>
            <button>Update Watch</button>
            <button onClick={() => {deleteWatchListing(watch.id)}}>Delete Listing</button>
          </form>  
        </div>
```

I tried putting the file url in, but it is different to the image url I get back from firebase when I use getDownloadUrl. I am able to get all the images from firebase currently, just not indivual ones.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add your code that you use to upload image and document in Firestore at first place? It'll help us get more context and identify the issue you are facing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

yes, I have also faced that issue. But that has been resolved by adding these permissions.[image]
OR
You can follow the following steps:-

1. https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser?project=YOUR_PROJECT_NAME&supportedpurview=project&cloudshell=true
   2.select our project.
2. click on open shell (it may take 1min to open)
3. command: gsutil cors set cors.json gs://YOURPROJECTNAME.appspot.com/* [image]

Comment: 1. https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser?project=lyodatatest&supportedpurview=project&cloudshell=true  2. click on open shell                                    
 3. command: gsutil cors set cors.json gs://YOURPROJECTNAME.appspot.com/*

Comment: Yeah its more the actual task of getting the image rather then being allowed to get the images. This was something I did have to figure out earlier though :)

Comment: update the CORS setting as I suggested in 2nd method. follow these steps and please let me know. thanks